# Why my graphs are not bipartite, thought I create them as bipartite using corresponding networkx function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, networkx

I have written a function:

```
B = nx.Graph()
B.add_nodes_from([1, 2, 3, 4], bipartite=0)
B.add_nodes_from(["a", "b", "c"], bipartite=1)
B.add_edges_from([(1, "a"), (1, "b"), (2, "b"), (2, "c"), (3, "c"), (4, "a"), (1,2)])
layout = nx.bipartite_layout(B, [1, 2, 3, 4])
nx.draw_networkx(B, pos=layout)
```

As you see, this graph must be bipartite, however I get this:

[image]

1 and 2 are connected. so, if i can add edges between them using this `B.add_edges_from([(1, "a"), (1, "b"), (2, "b"), (2, "c"), (3, "c"), (4, "a"), (1,2)])`, what is a point of wring this: `B.add_nodes_from([1, 2, 3, 4], bipartite=0)` and specifying that its bipartite?

Answer (score 0):

You've assigned the nodes an attribute `bipartite=0` or `1`.  However, that's just an attribute of the nodes.  You can assign them any attribute you want, with any name (a color, a weight, a species name, etc) - it has no impact on what edges exist. In particular, there's no special attention paid to the name of the attribute.  You've named an attribute `'bipartite'`, but as far as the networkx commands are concerned you could have just as easily named that attribute `'fubar'`.  It doesn't care.

You added an edge between nodes 1 and 2.  Networkx won't look at the attributes of the graph and make a choice to refuse to allow you the edge you asked it to create.

In your case, I think the answer to your question is that there doesn't seem to be a point in setting an attribute named `'bipartite'`.