# Bipartite graph problems

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, matplotlib, networkx

this one is my code...i dont know why the plot show like this

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
from networkx.algorithms import bipartite
B = nx.Graph()
B.add_nodes_from([1, 2, 3, 4], bipartite=0)
B.add_nodes_from(["a", "b", "c"], bipartite=1)
B.add_edges_from([(1, "a"), (1, "b"), (2, "b"), (2, "c"), (3, "c"), (4, "a")])
nx.draw_networkx(B)
plt.show(B)
```

why result look wrong?why dont show 2 set separately
[image]

if i want to draw graph like this picture ...what should i do?how to use bipartite layout, can anyone help me to write this code
[image]

Comment: Given that someone else asked a very closely related question yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66158192/why-my-graphs-are-not-bipartite-thought-i-create-them-as-bipartite-using-corres  I'm assuming this is a homework problem.  So I'll give guidance but not an answer.  You've never told `networkx` that it should plot the graph in a way that shows the bipartite nature of the graph.  So it's just plotting it normally.  Look at the bipartite layout features of` networkx` for ways to do what you want.

Comment: @Joel thank you so much for your guidance

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
from networkx.algorithms import bipartite
B = nx.Graph()
n = [1, 2, 3, 4]
l = [*'abc']
B.add_nodes_from(n, bipartite=0)
B.add_nodes_from(l, bipartite=1)
B.add_edges_from([(1, "a"), (1, "b"), (2, "b"), (2, "c"), (3, "c"), (4, "a")])
pos = dict()
pos.update( (n, (1, i)) for i, n in enumerate(n) ) 
pos.update( (n, (2, i)) for i, n in enumerate(l) ) 

nx.draw_networkx(B, pos=pos)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(B, pos=pos, nodelist=n, node_color='G')
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(B,  node_shape='s', pos=pos, nodelist=l, node_color='r')

nx.draw_networkx_labels(B, pos, font_color='white',
                        labels={i:i for i in l})

plt.axis('off')
plt.show(B)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @ahmad Did this solution help you?

Comment: thank @Scott Boston you so much my friend...its really helpful for me, just i have one another  question, if i want to increase my nodes to 200 node (n=100 and l =100) and also have 280 edges randomly...how to make this network?can you help me?
thank you so much for your attention again

Comment: thank  you so much my friend...its really helpful for me, just i have one another question, if i want to increase my nodes to 200 node (n=100 and l =100) and also have 280 edges randomly...how to make this network?can you help me? thank you so much for your attention again

Comment: That question is not specific enough. Needs more focus.